# Why does ubuntu consume 25% of the CPUs while beeing idle?

Tags: 14.04, server, cpu, cpu-load

I am experiencing 25% CPU usage on a ubuntu 14.04.03 server which is supposed to be idle. According to htop, load is about 1.0 while the underlying proccess all show 0 to nothing of CPU load.

There are no special services running as I stoped all of them to identify the cause. The high CPU consumption now holds for over 24 hours.

How can I determine the process and fix this issue?

This is a screen shot of htop:

[image: Ubuntu htop]

This is a screen shot of top, showing Zookeeper to be responsible for it:

[image]

Comment: Where did you get that 25%?

Comment: This is an estimate. It is eating significant CPU as you see on the load and the cpu bars. It runns along with 2 other nodes on a MacBook Pro Host within Virtualbox. The other 2 hosts have 0 CPU, while this one causes the Macbook to have about 25% of its CPU dedicated to the VM instance.

Comment: Now that you found out what process causes the load, you could maybe research a bit yourself what this `zookeeper` usually does and [edit] your answer to include this information...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**htop** is lying. It displays average. 
CPU is not a pipe and can not be filled to some extent. It is either working on some frequency or not at all. You can only talk about load value if it is consistent. If it is not, the simple math does not work. An average of four measures: `0 0 100 0` - is 25, but it does not mean that something is using 25% of CPU power. It means something has started, did its job and quit.

Comment: You are right, "top" has identified zookeeper as the 25% Process. Now the remaining question is... why?!

Comment: watch your io, e.g. with `iotop`